# Acessar opção do objeto sem ser com ponto

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Eu tenho um objeto **json** no javascript e preciso acessa-lo,atualmente estava acessando suas opções assim:

```
registro.man_ins_prod_05
```

Entretando no hightchart na parte de adicionar valores(data) no gráfico,eles tratam **pontos** como **virgula**.
Exemplo funcional:

```
data: [5.2, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
```

E caso eu coloque:

```
data: [registro.man_ins_prod_05, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
```

Não funciona.Existe alguma maneira de acionar a opção sem ser por **ponto**?

Comment: Eu sei que o problema está resolvido, mas a pergunta está confusa. Usar `registro.man_ins_prod_05` é idêntico a usar `registro['man_ins_prod_05']`. Os números em `data` você não consegue acessar como chaves porque são valores, aquilo é uma array e não um objeto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode acessar ele da seguinte forma: `registro["man_ins_prod_05"]`.

Comment: Obrigado,funcionou

Comment: Neste caso, poderia aceitar a resposta?

Comment: Acho que quem tem baixa reputação não pode marcar uma resposta como válida

Comment: não considero 157 uma pontuação baixa ;D

Comment: Não tinha marcado,pois tem tempo minimo para aceitar a resposta

Comment: TobyMosque, vale uma olhada aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1425/devemos-pedir-para-aceitar-resposta

Comment: @bfavaretto, falha minha, está anotado.